# Only send one email for each group of calls to a REST API function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to send one email each time a user makes a batch of calls to the API function below (I'm using Django REST framework to implement this interface).

In each run of their client software the user may make upto 1000 calls to this api. I do not want an email for each call just one at the start. Each batch of calls will not last longer than 10 minutes.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def record_add(request):                                                      
    """
    Add or update a record.
    """

    # work something out so only only sends one for each batch of calls
    #message = '%s using api' % request.user
    #mail_admins(message, message)
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store an `email_timeout` value in the users table and check it on each request. If the current time is after the timeout, set the timeout to current timeout + 10 minutes and send a mail, otherwise skip the mail.

Comment: I like it. I'm using custom users, so this will be easy. I will give it a go. Thanks.